# Which Taylor expansion is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and I would like to compute the Taylor expansion of $y = x + \delta v$ around $x$ for $\delta > 0$ small. I am very confused because there seem to be two different expressions for the expansions and in my problem at hand, they lead to different results.

#### Expansion 1

$$
\begin{equation}
f(y) = f(x) + \delta v^\top \nabla f(x) + \frac{\delta^2}{2}v^\top\nabla^2 f(x) v + \mathcal{O}(\delta^3) 
\end{equation}
$$

#### Expansion 2

$$
\begin{equation}
f(y) = f(x) + \delta v^\top \nabla f(x) + \frac{\delta^2}{2}v^\top \nabla^2 f(x^-) v
\end{equation}
$$
where $x^-$ lies on the line between $y$ and $x$.

---

> Which one is the correct expansion?

Comment: I edited it because I had a typo. The first $\nabla f(x)$ is the gradient, whereas $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is the Hessian.

Answer (score 2):

Expansion 1 is correct if $f$ is $C^3$. Expansion 2 is correct if $f$ is $C^2$. In expansion 1, you expanded to order two and wrote the remainder as $O(\delta^3)$. In expansion 2 you used the Lagrange form of the remainder.

All multivariate Taylor expansion remainder formulas can de derived by applying the [one variable formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20calculus%2C%20Taylor%27s%20theorem%20gives,Taylor%20series%20of%20the%20function.) to the map $\phi : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(t) = f(x + t\delta v)$.

Comment: Thank you! I am confused, in the last paragraph what do you mean by one variable formulas?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I added a link to the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

In brief: your first equation is a 2nd order Taylor approximation with error bound; whereas your second equation is a 1st order Taylor approximation with exact error expression.

Let me break this down more.

To understand your second equation, one can first write it in the form of a "1st order Taylor approximation":
$$f(x + \delta v) \approx f(x) + \delta v^T \nabla f(x)
$$
This is of course **not** an equation, but what it is intended to convey is that the difference between the two sides is somehow "small". Let me introduce some notation for that difference, what I'll call the *1st order error term*
$$E_1(x,\delta) = f(x + \delta v) - \left(f(x) + \delta v^T \nabla f(x)\right)
$$
We can use this notation to rewrite the approximate equation as a true equation:
$$f(x + \delta v) = f(x) + \delta v^T \nabla f(x) + E_1(x,\delta)
$$
Fine so far, nothing deep is happening yet, all we did was to introduce new notation.

The difficulty with the error term is although we do have some exact formulas for it, those formulas are usually expressed in a way that makes it impossible to evaluate the error term exactly.

For example, one of those exact formulas is the second one that you have written, although you have omitted a **VERY** important part of that formula, namely the existential quantifier "there exists":

> There exists $x_-$ on the line segment between $y$ and $x$ such that
> $$E_1(x,\delta) = \frac{\delta^2}{2}v^\top \nabla^2 f(x^-) v
> $$

The reason that we cannot evaluate $E_1(x,\delta)$ exactly using this formula is that we do not know the exact value of $x_-$ along that line segment.

Your first equation, on the other hand, should be thought of as a second order Taylor approximation, and again I will rewrite it using the 2nd order error term $E_2(x,\delta)$:
$$f(y) = f(x) + \delta v^\top \nabla f(x) + \frac{\delta^2}{2}v^\top\nabla^2 f(x) v + E_2(x,\delta)
$$
It is possible to write out an exact expression for $E_2(x,\delta)$ which (like the 1st order error term) depends on an unknown point $x_-$ between $x$ and $\delta$ and so is impossible to evaluate exactly.

However, what we can do with these exact error expressions is sometimes use them to deduce error bounds. For example, we would like a bound of the form
$$| E_2(x,\delta) | \le \text{SOMETHING}
$$
For example, one such error bound is what you have written in your first equation:
$$|E_2(x,\delta)| = \mathcal{O}(\delta^3)
$$
This is meaningless unless you know what that "big O" notation actually means. It is not intended as an exact equation. Instead it means:

> There exists $M > 0$, depending on $x$ but independent of $\delta$, such that
> $$|E_2(x,\delta)| \le M \delta^3
> $$

The hard work underlying Taylor approximations and error terms is two fold: finding an exact expression for the error term, usually depending on some unknown quantity such as $x_-$; and then using the exact expression to find an error bound, usually having some form similar to $\mathcal O(\delta^3)$.